# JObject.parse not working

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using `JObject.Parse` to parse a JSON string. The value is `"parameterValues={\r\n  \"DE:Actual Savings\": 42217.0\r\n}"`

I tried the following but it's not working. Is it because of the special characters?

```
var val = JToken.Parse(oldRecord[2]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is for the `parameterValues=` part, you need to stripe that out of the string

Comment: There also should not be newlines in the json.

Comment: the new lines and tabs are negligibles (if the json is well Indented) pasing a  JsonSerializerSettings with JsonSerializerSettings.Formating = Formating.Indented as second parameter of the method.